# Wifi on windows 8 is not displaying routers

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

Till yesterday, wifi connections from my windows 8 PC were working fine. Today, no wifi devices are getting listed.

[image]

While trying to troubleshoot this, I've been told that wifi can be turned on from -> Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Wireless:

But I see only a blank screen here:
[image]

According to few sources on the web, I'm supposed to see atleast two options over here: *(Image from Web below)*
[image]

But I don't see these two options. What could I be missing?

Another suggestion was to ensure wifi is turned on using a hardware button or function key on the (Compaq 6710b) Laptop I have. But the laptop does not seem to have either of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor that repaired my laptop had to change the Wireless Network Card to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with your laptop, but look better, there should be a wireless switch or button combination.

Another issue might be that Wireless card driver is not propely installed and doesn't work. This can happen if Windows Update found a new driver, tried to install it but didn't manage to successfully finish the installation.

Go to Control Panel, Device Manager and see if there is any network adapter without drivers or  with a yellow `!` on it. If so, reinstall the drivers (go from an another computer to manufacturer's site or use a cable to download it), and you should be OK.

Comment: Will you be using paragraphs soon?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with window 8. After the upgrade to window 8 from any other window or sometimes window 8 itself download & install the update available...

As a result window 8 WiFi driver may corrupt. This can also result in stop working of WiFi. Sometimes it also notice that WiFi button also stop working...In this case we recommend that you will re-install the WiFi Driver again.

If you buy the laptop/computer with pre loaded copy of window 8, you can locate the WiFi Drivers in "Window Drive". Most of the time it is Drive C:

Window Drive (Usually Drive C:)  >>>> SWsetup >>>> Drivers  >>>>RaWLAN

Run the setup.exe and restart the computer and you are done.

In case you had upgraded your computer to Window 8 you can find your computer or laptop driver here:

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html

The above link is for HP USA Site. If you are living in some other country, you can go to HP global site Now select your county.

Click on Support & Drivers, Must on the 1st page. Enter the Model Number or Product. Download the WiFi Driver, Install and Restart your computer.

Sometimes there are more than 2 WiFi Driver.  You have to select from the two. If one not work then second will work surely.

For more information & help you can see the below article.

http://www.webburr.com/window-8/wifi-button-not-working-window-8/578